# Link person's location to a person SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database to keep information about people and their location but I'm not sure how to link their location to them. I also want to keep track of their previous locations. So far I've got:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE locations (
`location_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`last_updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL    
);

CREATE TABLE persons_location (
`person_id` INT NOT NULL,
`location_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`person_id`, `location_name`)
);
```

It works currently like this but it means that I can't have multiple people with the same location.

How could I change it to enable this? I.e. User - 'Jim' has location Home and so does 'Sally' but then if they update their location it keeps it.

Comment: This datamodel *does* allow you to have multiple people at the same location, as the PK consists of person + location. You cannot store the same person and location twice however, but you want this as you want to keep track of previous locations. And you certainly want to know the series of locations. As long as you only store different locations per person, you never know which is current, which was before that and so on.

Comment: Oh thanks that makes more sense. So it I wanted to insert a new person and their current location what query would I use? Before I manually added it.

Comment: You add a new person with `insert into person (id, username, first_name, last_name) values (50, 'HARRYSMITH', 'Harry', 'Smith');` You enter his location with `insert into persons_location (person_id, location_name, presence_time) values (50, 'HOME', now());`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it. So if I wanted to find the latest location of a user what would I do? I had: SELECT p.*, l.*
FROM person p
INNER JOIN person_location pl
ON pl.person_id = p.id
INNER JOIN locations l
ON l.location_name = pl.location_name
WHERE p.username = 'harry smith'

Comment: I also ordered it and limited it to one.

Comment: Yes, for one person that's a good idea. Order by date and keep the last one. For more persons see the query I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of previous locations, you need a column indicating when a person was in a location:

```
CREATE TABLE persons_location (
  person_id INT NOT NULL,
  location_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  presence_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(person_id, location_name, presence_time)
);
```

**UPDATE:** The typical way to get the persons' last locations:

```
select
from
(
  select
    person_id,
    max(presence_time) as presence_time
  from person_location
  group by person_id
) last_time
join person_location pl on pl.person_id = last_time.person_id
                     and pl.presence_time = last_time.presence_time
join person p on p.id = pl.person_id
join location l on l.location_name = pl.location_name;
```

Comment: I thought I was achieving that using the last_updated field. Plus the main issue is that I can't have multiple people with the same location in locations?

Comment: last_updated should depend on the person, so it belongs to the relation table persons_location, otherwise you're forcing every one on this address to have same last_updated

Comment: @Andrew Gittus: No. `last_updated` only tells you when a location was last updated, whatever this means. But you want to know when a person was in a location, so you need a date/time in table persons_location instead.

Comment: Fixed it with a few tweaks, but it returns empty. I added the data from the previous comment.

Comment: It's because locations is empty? Do I have to add the location to locations each time I add one?

Comment: There are persons. When you deal with a new person not yet in the table, you must add it. There are locations. When you deal with a new location not yet in the table, you must add it. When adding a location-people combination, reference the person and the location (which you added either long time ago or just then to their tables).

Comment: And of course: `persons_location.location_name` should be a foreign key to `location.location_name` and `persons_location.person_id` should be a foreign key to `person.id`. Thus you can only add valid locations and persons that already exist in their respective table.